# Currently How to test a callback function with JEST + React?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I would like to test this component:

1. the parameter received in `onClick={() => onConfirmVote(number)}`
2. The value returned in `getVoteText`

**MY CODE:**

```
function CandidateList({ data }: IProps) {
    const { convertToCurrency, convertToPercentage } = useNumberConversion();

    const getVoteText = useCallback(
        (total: number, percentage: number) => `${convertToCurrency(total)} (${convertToPercentage(percentage)})`,
        [convertToCurrency, convertToPercentage]
    );

    return (
        <ListGroup data-testid='candidate-list-component'>
            {data.map(({ onConfirmVote, avatar, number, votesConfirmed, hasVoted }) => (
                <ListGroup.Item key={`${number}`} as='li' className='d-flex flex-wrap gap-2 align-items-center'>
                    <div className='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100'>
                        <div className='d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center gap-2'>
                            <Avatar alt={`Candidate #${number}`} src={avatar} />
                            <h5 className='fw-bold mb-0'>#{number}</h5>
                        </div>

                        <div className='mt-1 d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center gap-2'>
                            <span className='mb-1'>Votes:</span>

                            <Badge bg='primary' pill style={{ width: '155px' }} data-testid='badge-vote-value-component'>
                                {getVoteText(votesConfirmed.total, votesConfirmed.totalPercentage)}
                            </Badge>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <Button className='w-100' variant='success' onClick={() => onConfirmVote(number)} disabled={hasVoted}>
                        CONFIRM
                    </Button>
                </ListGroup.Item>
            ))}
        </ListGroup>
    );
}
```

**MY TESTE CODE:**

```
describe('[CANDIDATE LIST] - Testing Confirm Vote Button Component', () => {
    test('Should be work on click to Confirm Vote!', () => {
        render(<CandidateList data={MOCKED_DATA} />);

        const confirmVoteButton = screen.getAllByRole('button');

        confirmVoteButton.forEach(button => {
            console.log(button);
            expect(fireEvent.click(button)).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your component and you can try sth like this:

- the component

```js
import React from "react";

const ManyButtons = ({ data }) => {

  const getVoteText = (total, percentage) => `${total} (${percentage})`;

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(({ onConfirmVote, number, votesConfirmed: { total, totalPercentage } }, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <div>{getVoteText(total, totalPercentage)}</div>
          <button onClick={() => onConfirmVote(number)}>
            CONFIRM
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ManyButtons;
```

The test:

```js
import { screen, render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import ManyButtons from "../ManyButton";

const mockOnConfirmVote = jest.fn();
const mockedData = [
  { onConfirmVote: mockOnConfirmVote, number: 1, votesConfirmed: { total: 1, totalPercentage: 1 } },
  { onConfirmVote: mockOnConfirmVote, number: 2, votesConfirmed: { total: 2, totalPercentage: 2 } },
  { onConfirmVote: mockOnConfirmVote, number: 3, votesConfirmed: { total: 3, totalPercentage: 3 } },
]

describe('it should work', () => {
  it('should work', () => {
    render(<ManyButtons data={mockedData} />);

    const buttons = screen.getAllByRole('button', { name: /confirm/i });

    expect(buttons).toHaveLength(mockedData.length);

    buttons.forEach(btn => fireEvent.click(btn))

    expect(mockOnConfirmVote).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(buttons.length);

    mockedData.forEach(({ number, votesConfirmed: { total, totalPercentage }}) => {
      expect(mockOnConfirmVote).toHaveBeenCalledWith(number);
      expect(screen.getByText(`${total} (${totalPercentage})`)).toBeInTheDocument();
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: But if you don't use the function itself that is in the component, but do it the way you did with a mocked function, you wouldn't really be testing the component and its operation, would you?

Comment: Which function? `onConfirmVote` is coming from outside, it is not defined in the component. And if you mean `getVoteText` then I am not mocking it, just checking if component displays the correct result of it.